# C# Protractor test frame work does not work on Angular pages after migrating the application to Docker on Linux

Tags: c#, angular, docker, selenium, protractor-net

I have used the following framework for UI tests of an angular application and both version worked perfectly. Test code and app source code were on TFS, Windows virtual machines.

- Version 1: SpecFlow, SpecFlow + SpecRun3, C# selenium web driver, Page Object Model, protractor.
- Version 2: Spec Flow, Nunit,  C# selenium web driver, Page Object Model, protractor.

Environment : Framework="net461", Docker 2.2.0.5 (43884), Ubuntu 18.04

Note: [protractor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Protractor/) is a Nuget package to test angular pages and works as perfect as [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/)  itself without using any explicit waits.

Protractor stopped locating webelements on the angular pages after moving the the application to Linux - Docker containers and the error is "Message: script timeout".

```
public class HomePage 
{

    public HomePage()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.GetNgDriver(), this);         
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = " //button[@class='button-asd']")]
    public IWebElement HomeButton { get; set; }

}
```

When I cahange the driver type in the constructor of the angular page  as "PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.GetDriver(), this);" then it becomes ordinary C# + selenium and we have to deal with all web elements individually by using explicit waits.
The problem repeated in the same manner on these conditions.

- Application is on Linux - Docker & test code is on windows machine
- Application is on Linux - Docker & test code is on Linux -Docker

I want to use my simple, clear code without explicit waits as before.

```
pages.HomePage().HomeButton.Click();
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Check this protractor option: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled

Comment: this solution may work for regular Protractor approach. I use c# and protractor Nuget package which does not have such an option, thank you